# Is it possible that feedback vertex set problem has an $O(k^2/\log k)$ kernel？

Tags: kernelization

(This question also suits for other similar natural $\mathrm{NP}$-hard problems)

I know that there is a $4k^2$ vertex kernel (and $8k^2$ edge kernel) by Thomasse [[Thomasse09]](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.419.2070&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for Feedback Vertex Set (FVS) problem.

Harnik and Naor [[HN06]](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Enaor/PAPERS/compressibility.pdf) introduced a notion of compression with the goal of succinctly storing instances of computational problems.

As argued by Dell and van Melkebeek [[DV14]](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220268341_Satisfiability_Allows_No_Nontrivial_Sparsification_Unless_The_Polynomial-Time_Hierarchy_Collapses), for every real number $\varepsilon > 0$, FVS does not admits a polynomial compression with bitsize $O(k^{2−\varepsilon})$, unless $\mathrm{NP} \subseteq \mathrm{coNP/poly}$.
It shows that obtaining kernels for the FVS problems with a strictly subquadratic number of edges is implausible (since $O(k^{2−\varepsilon})$ edges can be encoded in $O(k^{2−\varepsilon}\log k)$ bits).

However, it seems hard to understand, using solely the notion of the compositions as a tool, whether obtaining a kernel for FVS with a subquadratic number of vertices is possible or not.

Is it possible that FVS has an $O(k^2/\log k)$ kernel?
In general, if there do exist an $O(\mathrm{poly}(k))$ kernel for a natural (graph) problem and it has a lower bound of size $O(\mathrm{poly}(k))$ bit. Is it still possible that this problem has an $O(\mathrm{poly}(k)/\log k)$ kernel?
Do we have any evidences or obversations to believe or doubt it?